# Why does calling printJS() in the react component fail?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, printjs

I tried to call the printJS in react Component,but it didn't work when i clicked the button.Then I modified the code look like this.

```
 <button  onClick={printJS({printable:'docs/test.pdf',type:'pdf'})}>
                Print {this.state.type} with Message
 </button>
```

it works  automatically when i first open the page but the click button is still invalid.

```
import React from 'react';
import printJS from 'print-js';


class PrintButton extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            name:'',
            type:'pdf',
        };
        this.handleNameChange=this.handleNameChange.bind(this);
        this.handleTypeChange=this.handleTypeChange.bind(this);
        this.print=this.print.bind(this);
    }

    handleNameChange(e){
        this.setState({name:e.target.value});
    }
    handleTypeChange(e){
        this.setState({type:e.target.value});
    }

    print(){
        let url;
        if(this.state.type==='pdf'){
            url=`docs/${this.state.name}`;
        }else if(this.state.type==='image'){
            url=`images/${this.state.name}`;
        }else if(this.state.type==='html'){
            url=`${this.state.name}`;
        }else{
            url=this.state.name;
        }
        printJS({printable:url,type:this.state.type});
    } 

    render(){
        return(
         <form>
            <label>
                选择类型:
                <select value={this.state.type} onChange={this.handleTypeChange}>
                <option value="pdf">PDF</option>
                <option value="image">IMAGE</option>
                <option value="html">HTML</option>
                <option value="json">JSON</option>
                </select>
            </label>
            <input value={this.state.name} type='text' onChange={this.handleNameChange}/>
            <button  onClick={this.print}>
                Print {this.state.type} with Message
            </button>
         </form>
        );

    }
}

export default PrintButton;
```

i  want to design a printable react Component

Comment: What do you mean when you say it fails? Is `printJS` undefined? Do you see any error in console?

Comment: @mgarcia Print page does not appear

Comment: `<button  onClick={() => printJS({printable:'docs/test.pdf',type:'pdf'})}>` use arrow function while calling function inline. What is the issue you are getting while using `this.print` function

Comment: There is no need for that, as he is binding the `print` method in the class constructor.

Comment: @潘夏开, are you seeing something on the console?

Comment: @ mgarcia  the reason i find is in <form> tag,when i replaced <form> with <>,it works

Comment: @ tarzen chugh thank you for you help

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you have a `button` inside a `form`. As you are not specifying a `type` attribute for the [button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button), the default value is `submit`:

> submit: The button submits the form data to the server. This is the default if the attribute is not specified, or if the attribute is dynamically changed to an empty or invalid value.

Hence, when you click on the button you are submitting the form. You can avoid that by calling `preventDefault` on the click [`event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault):

```
 print(ev){
    let url;

    ev.preventDefault();

    if(this.state.type==='pdf'){
        url=`docs/${this.state.name}`;
    }else if(this.state.type==='image'){
        url=`images/${this.state.name}`;
    }else if(this.state.type==='html'){
        url=`${this.state.name}`;
    }else{
        url=this.state.name;
    }
    printJS({printable:url,type:this.state.type});
}
```